# Linq to Entities Relationship Join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How do I write the following SQL in linq to entities? I am trying to get all users with access to a forum which are assigned using forum groups.

```
SELECT UsersInForumGroups.UserId FROM Forums
JOIN ForumsInForumGroups on Forums.ForumId = ForumsInForumGroups.ForumId
JOIN ForumGroups on ForumGroups.ForumGroupId = ForumsInForumGroups.ForumGroupId
JOIN UsersInForumGroups on UsersInForumGroups.ForumGroupId = ForumGroups.ForumGroupId
WHERE Forums.ForumId = 'blah'
```

I have all the relationships setup using SQL foreign keys and they are working in entity framework e.g. this syntax is working.

```
db.ForumsInForumGroups.Select(x=>x.ForumGroup)
```

As requested here is the entity setup

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think in linq to entities you no need to create a join query because all tables having relationship are self join.So just need to get value from parent table and their child will be get easily from them. like `parenttablename.Childtable.fieldname`

Comment: You'll need to post what your entities look like too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a many-to-one relationship between your tabels, it could look like this:

```
var res = db.Forums.Include("ForumsInForumGroups.ForumGroups.UsersInForumGroups")
            .Where(c => c.ForumId == "blah")
            .Select(c => c.ForumsInForumGroups
                          .ForumGroups
                          .UsersInForumGroups
                          .UserId)
```

**Edit**
there is no need for the `Include` then you are selecting through relations:

```
var res = db.Forums.Where(c => c.ForumId == "blah")
            .Select(c => c.ForumsInForumGroups
                          .ForumGroups
                          .UsersInForumGroups
                          .UserId)
```

**Edit 2**
I was a bold assumsion :)
Try this:

```
var res = db.Forums.Where(c => c.ForumId == "blah")
            .SelectMany(c => c.ForumsInForumGroups
                          .SelectMany(q => q.ForumGroups.UsersInForumGroups
                              .Select(z => z.UserId)
                                     )
                        );
```

Comment: With the second solution I get
Error 7 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<EFLayer.ForumsInForumGroup>' does not contain a definition for 'ForumGroups' and no extension method 'ForumGroups' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<EFLayer.ForumsInForumGroup>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The relationships on SQL server all seem to be correct, i.e. all one-to-many, there are no many-to-manys.

E.g. One ForumGroups may have many ForumsInForumGroups